# unbind the event in jquery mousewheel event

Tags: jquery

[Using the hscroll as in the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SyAz/q3pf2hge/36/)
looking to unbind the event after the div horizontal scroll ends

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
    $.fn.hScroll = function (amount) {
        amount = amount || 120;
        $(this).bind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel", function (event) {
            var oEvent = event.originalEvent, 
                direction = oEvent.detail ? oEvent.detail * -amount : oEvent.wheelDelta, 
                position = $(this).scrollLeft();
            position += direction > 0 ? -amount : amount;
            $(this).scrollLeft(position);
            event.preventDefault();
        })
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [reference](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and choose the `off` or `unbind` based on your jquery version.

Where you can use something

```
$(this).off("DOMMouseScroll");
```

or

```
$(this).off("mousewheel");
```

Comment: i am new to jquery so could u help me in my fiddle? where to use it?

Comment: ya the event is getting unbind but i was infact looking to unbind it on horizontal scroll end of the div and again bind it on the start of the horizontal div